# printing a menu in python

Tags: python, menu

I was asked to create a primitive version of a store and create a menu to help manage that store.
The problem is that after each option in the menu I am supposed to reprint the menu and in case a valid option wasn't given by the user print the message "unsupported operation", but for some reason the message is printed even if the operation was valid (the program performs the task correctly but still prints the message every time)

```
def main():
    store = dict()
    file = open("store.txt", 'r')  # dont forget to change it so sys.argv[1]
    create_store(store, file)
    print_menu()
    user_choice = input()
    while True:
        if user_choice == '0':
            file.close()
            return
        if user_choice == '1':
            query_by_category(store)
        if user_choice == '2':
            return
        if user_choice == '3':
            return
        if user_choice == '4':
            return
        else:
            print("Error: unrecognized operation.")
        print_menu()
        user_choice = input()
```

Comment: You need to indent `print_menu()` under `else` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not using one `if-else` block, but 5 different ones:

Change

```py
if user_choice == '0':
    file.close()
    return
if user_choice == '1':
    query_by_category(store)
if user_choice == '2':
    return
if user_choice == '3':
    return
if user_choice == '4':
    return
else:
    print("Error: unrecognized operation.")
```

to:

```py
if user_choice == '0':
    file.close()
    return
elif user_choice == '1':
    query_by_category(store)
elif user_choice == '2':
    return
elif user_choice == '3':
    return
elif user_choice == '4':
    return
else:
    print("Error: unrecognized operation.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the print_menu() twice, so instead of this reduntant operation try to start the while-statement with calling it, with this you can remove 2 lines of code. Also you use empty return statements, that is really not needed. A placeholder for upcoming code is "pass".

```
def main():
    store = dict()
    file = open("store.txt", 'r')  # dont forget to change it so sys.argv[1]
    create_store(store, file)
    while True:
        print_menu()
        user_choice = input()
        if user_choice == '0':
            file.close()
        elif user_choice == '1':
            query_by_category(store)
        elif user_choice == '2':
            pass
        elif user_choice == '3':
            pass
        elif user_choice == '4':
            pass
        else:
            print("Error: unrecognized operation.")
```